# Rotate cone to align with sphere normal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

Hello I am trying to create floating islands on planets, but I need to rotate the floating island so it looks correct, this is how it looks currently
[![World Up][1]][1][![][2]][2][![World Left][3]][3]
As you can hopefully see, the cones don't align with the surface as the surface curves away from facing the world up direction

I am creating a density volume with SDFs and using marching cubes to generate the mesh.
Here is the SDF code :

```
float sdCone(float3 p)
{
   p -= column * v[0].island;

   float2 c = float2(0.5, 0.5);
   float h = 0.45;

   float q = length(p.xz);
   return v[0].islandR - max(dot(c.xy, float2(q, -p.y)), h + p.y);
}
```

So how can I rotate the cones to the correct orientation?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVISH.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LcK1.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xzA0.png

Comment: Geometrically (I don't know unity), I would draw a line from the center coordinate of the cone to the center of the sphere. That line will be parallel to how you want your cone and normal to the surface of the sphere.

Comment: @Steve I think I just need to multiply the p.xz by something that will rotate it